# What is the Varchar(Max) equivalent for DB2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2, varchar

In DB2, is there a datatype that allows the string to grow and shrink dynamically like the Varchar(Max) datatype in SQL Server database?

Comment: Has either answer satisfied your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, according to [this](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/oracle-guide/a-comparison-of-data-types-between-various-databases-oracle-mysql-db2-ingres-sql-server-firebird-postgres-33209) and [this](http://www.connx.com/products/connx/Connx%208.6%20UserGuide/CONNXCDD32C/DB2_Data_Types.htm), DB2 doesn't have a large capacity text type.

You can use the `VARCHAR(n)` data type for text. Please keep in mind that `n` is the [maximum length of bytes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/intro/src/tpc/db2z_stringdatatypes.html) and not the character length. The maximum length is 32704 in byte. This is important if you are using a UTF-8 encoded database.

Comment: It's CLOB but your link fails to match this with varchar... http://wiki.gxtechnical.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Data+types+of+attributes+in+the+DBMS,

Comment: in db2 v10, its [32704](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_stringdatatypes.htm)

Comment: In version db2 9.7, the highest I can go is 32672: CAST(tableName.clobField as varchar(32672))
--32673 fails.

Comment: `Please keep in mind that n is the maximum length of bytes and not the character length.` in case when you are saving varchar, won't the value of N be the total number of characters?

Answer (score 3):

It should be "CLOB"

Guffa's link does mention this but fails to match CLOB and VARCHAR.

Comment: I understood the question a little bit different and would answer it with yes. The datatype is called `varchar` (according to both links from Guffa. Zian just needs to define how big he needs max to be. It might differ than. May be he needs `long varchar`.

Comment: I think CLOB  can not shrink and every field would consume max bytes, so varchar(n) would be better. thanks.